# Multicasting with FIX

Tags: multicast, fix-protocol

I have a scenario in which a FIX server will send to multiple clients. I have found examples in which this is done by sending to each session round-robin fashion however, is there any facility in FIX that allows what might be called multicasting? I.e. all clients subscribe, for example, to a shared session.

Many thanks.

Comment: `round-robin` will be not optimal. It means I might receive a message long after another client. All FIX engines are multi threaded, so why are you doing round-robin.

Comment: This appears to be one attempt at FIX multicasting: http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/mod/file/view.php?file_guid=30528